# Heroku - Dyno Hours

Tags: heroku

I have a heroku account and host my Discord bot on it. Heroku said my dyno hours were running out so I added my card to get 450 additional hours. Will heroku charge me without me wanting anything? Also, do the dyno hours count for all apps or do they count individually? Like If I have 1000 dyno hours and 4 apps, will each app get 1000 hours or will the apps split the hours among my apps?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku won't charge you unless you've scaled up the dyno usage past the free tier on your app. Once you run out of hours, your app will be forced to sleep until the next month. Also, free dyno hours are shared across all of your apps. [source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours)